# Convert Vec<[f64;1]> to Vec<f64>

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and I am playing with it. When I was following some tutorial, I found a vector of type <[f64,1]>. I thought it should be simple to transform it to [f64] but could not find a simple way other than for loop. Is there other way?

```
let y: Vec<[f64;1]> = [[1],[2],[3],[4]];
let mut y2: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    for each in &y {
        y2.push(each[0]);
}
```

Comment: The error message is a little misleading. You need to construct the `y` vector like this: `let y: Vec<[f64;1]> = vec![[1.0],[2.0],[3.0],[4.0]];`. As you've done it, you are trying to assign an array to a vec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` in your example is not a Vec; you probably forgot `vec!` in front.
Furthermore, floats should be `1.0` not `1`.

I don't know why you find this for loop not simple, but if you want other ways:

### Using iterator pattern

```
let y: Vec<[f64; 1]> = vec![[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]];
let y2: Vec<f64> = y.iter().map(|&[f]| f).collect();
```

### Using unsafe

Since `[f64; 1]` and `f64` are equal-sized (both 8 bytes),
we can transmute the `Vec` directly:

```
let y: Vec<[f64; 1]> = vec![[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]];
let y2 = unsafe {
    // Ensure the original vector is not dropped.
    let mut y = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(y);
    Vec::from_raw_parts(y.as_mut_ptr() as *mut f64,
                        y.len(),
                        y.capacity())
};
```

This is more complex, but it will reuse the same memory without copying.

Comment: On nightly, you can use [`Vec::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts) instead of futzing about with `ManuallyDrop`. Hopefully this will be stabilized soon.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `flatten()` method:

```rust
let y_vec: Vec<f64> = y.iter().flatten().cloned().collect();
```